# A way to remove an element from an array based on the string length in the first element

Tags: arrays, indexing, lua, insert

Let’s say I have a question bank,
`qbank = {q1,q2,q3,...,qN}`
And the questions in it are filled entirely with string values like,
`q1 = {question,resp1,resp2,resp3,answer}`
The thing is, if the question (the first string element of q1) is filled with too many characters (40), I want it to be moved (inserted) to a table called qbanklarger.
I’d imagine it would require an index, but the thing is, I’d want to remove the question array from the original qbank as well.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well ideally don't add a question longer than 40 characters to qbank in the first place. put it into the qbaselarger right away.

So you could do something like this:

```
local Questions = {long = {}, short = {}}
function Questions:add(q)
  if #q.question >= 40 then
    table.insert(self.long, q)
  else
    table.insert(self.short, q)
  end
end
```

Or if you want to do it as planned you'll have to remove any long question from `qbank` and add it to `qbaselarger`.
See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.remove

Actually it is more efficient to sort them into new tables instead of removing from `qbase`. Because `table.remove` needs to shift all the following elements down once you've removed an element.

```
local buffer = {} -- this will be our new qbase with only short questions
for i,v in ipairs(qbase) do
  if #v.question >= 40 then
    table.insert(qbaselarger, v)  -- put long questions into qbaselarger
  else
    table.insert(buffer, v) -- and short questions into the buffer
  end
end
qbase = buffer -- now refer qbase to the buffer
buffer = nil  -- we don't need buffer anymore
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a if function to evaluate if the first item is larger than or equal to 40

```
qbanklarger=[]
if len(q1[1])>=40:
  qbanklarger.append(q1[1])
  np.delete(q1, q1[1])
```

This should work.

Comment: how is Python code with numpy arrays going to help him with his Lua code? Please read questions more carefully

Comment: `np.delete` would require a slice or index as second argument btw. following your logic `q1[1]` is a string. also the goal is not to remove `q1[1]` from `q1` but to remove `q1` if `q1[1]` is too long. of course this needs to be done for all the elements in `qbank`